# Examples of endomorphisms of complex curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking for examples of smooth projective complex curves $X$ of genus at least $2$ and with algebraic endomorphisms $f:X\rightarrow X$ of degree at least $2$. In the case of elliptic curves and $\mathbb{C}P^1$, such examples are easy to construct; however, if the genus is at least $2$, I don't know such examples. If we work over finite fields, then we can construct such examples using the Frobenius.

Comment: There are no such examples, by Riemann-Hurwitz. In general, varieties of general type over a field of characteristic zero have no positive degree endomorphisms, for if they did, they would have infinitely many self-maps, which is ruled out by a well-known result of Kobayashi, IIRC.

Comment: @Daniel Litt: What about varieties that are neither of general type nor abelian?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^n$ admits a lot of endomorphisms.

Comment: @user134541: I don't know a particularly clean statement -- one can always take your favorite genus 2 curve times an elliptic curve; this obviously has lots of high-degree endomorphisms.

Comment: A reference for what Daniel Litt said is Proposition 2 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0008205.pdf

Comment: There is a reasonable classification of surfaces admitting endomorphisms of degree > 1, due to Nakayama and collaborators.  The references to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.5984.pdf look like a place to start.  Classifying them in higher dimensions is hard (in part because classifying varieties in higher dimensions is hard).